# Using Cashier's subscription table for offline payments?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

Say I build and app, and I setup Cashier with Stripe and everything works fine but I also want to have an option for people making payments differently (say offline, by cheque).

Rather than building a separate system alongside Cashier, I'm thinking of "highjacking" Cashier's table. For example, I'm thinking I could set a subscription name, user_id, trials_ends_at, and ends_at "manually" in the app, without actually filling the other fields. That way I could have some other kind of payments, and still try and leverage Cashier's methods, or create my own, but not duplicate tables.

Is this a bad idea? (Probably.) But is it feasible? Doing so, would I break Cashier's regular utilisation?

Comment: Do you think about using a Stripe subscription with 0€ pricing for that kind of offline payments? It is only one idea.

Comment: @dmoreno I though about it, but not for a long time to be honest. I think that could work, but I'd still need to have the user enter it's CC infos and "deal with" stripe...

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray How are you?. Did you get any other solution for this? I'm looking for a solution to this. Planning to work with Laravel 6.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha it's been a while, and that project isn't active anymore, but I *think* I just manually added entries to the "subscription" tables and it worked, granted that I don't try to use other functions that are linked to Stripe directly.